# multiline-flexbox in IE11 calculating widths incorrectly?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, flexbox

Seems IE11 doesn't calculate flex item widths properly if `flex-wrap: wrap` is used.

See http://jsfiddle.net/MartijnR/WRn9r/6/

The 4 boxes each have flex-basis: 50% so we should get two lines of two boxes each, but in IE11 each box gets one line. When setting the border to 0, it works correctly.

Any idea if this is a bug, or if there is way to make IE11 behave (and still use borders)?

```
<section>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
</section>
```

```
section {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    -moz-flex: 50%;
    -webkit-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
}
```

P.S. In my project only the last version of popular browsers needs to be supported, thankfully, but IE11 is one of them.

Comment: suspecting this is a bug so have posted at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8145c1e8-6e51-4213-ace2-2cfa43b1c018/ie-11-flexbox-with-flexwrap-wrap-doesnt-seem-to-calculate-widths-correctly-boxsizing-ignored?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: May be a rounding issue. FWIW setting a max-width of 50% fixes it.

Comment: You have a typo in your code by the way: `-moz-webkit-flex`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It looks like a bug where `box-sizing` is not being taken into account when calculating the size using the `flex` property. As the border takes up 2px, it is larger than 50% and thus only one fits on a line, so all boxes are stretched to the full width. You can see the same thing happening if you disable the border and add 2px padding instead.

You can make it work correctly while keeping the borders by adding `max-width: 50%` to the `.box` ruleset. Otherwise you can use a flex value between 33.34% and 49%. This will make the width less than 50% including the border, and as the elements grow to fill available space, they’ll still be 50% of the flex container. Kind of a ugly hack, but it will work unless you add a combined border and padding larger than 50% minus the flex value you set.

Perhaps a better way than decreasing the percentage value directly is to use `calc()`. This is supported by all browsers that support the modern Flexbox syntax. You just need to subtract the combined total of the left and right paddings and margins from the percentage value you want to use. As you‘re doing this you don’t really need the box-sizing property so it can be removed. There seems to be another issue in IE where you can’t use calc in the `flex` shorthand but you can use it in the `flex-basis` property, which is the one you want.

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    /* additional styles removed for clarity */

    /* 
    50% - (border-left-width + border-right-width +
           padding-left + padding-right)
    */
    -webkit-flex-basis: calc(50% - 2px);
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 2px);
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dstorey/78q8m/3/

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a max-width would not make the boxes flex any more.

Comment: It does indeed look like a box-sizing bug though.

Comment: The second solution will work though. Although your solution above doesn’t work in Safari and Firefox, using this one will. Just make sure the 25% flex is under 25% but above the next smaller size. In the following demo I used 48% instead of 50 and 23% instead of 25, but you can adjust as needed: http://jsfiddle.net/WRn9r/25/

Comment: Here is a version without the redundant prefixes and classes http://jsfiddle.net/WRn9r/26/

Comment: I've added a version of the second solution using calc rather than just decreasing the % value, and switching to flex-basis.

Comment: Thanks David. Your workaround seem the only one that works, with this IE bug!

Comment: Been searching for a fix for some time now, exactly what I needed! Cheers

Comment: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/blob/master/README.md#flexbug-7

Answer (score 10):

I received an workaround on the Microsoft forum from Rob. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8145c1e8-6e51-4213-ace2-2cfa43b1c018/ie-11-flexbox-with-flexwrap-wrap-doesnt-seem-to-calculate-widths-correctly-boxsizing-ignored?forum=iewebdevelopment

Setting a `min-width` and changing to `flex:auto` makes the boxes behave, maintaining their *flexiness*.

See http://jsfiddle.net/MartijnR/WRn9r/23/ and below for a slightly more advanced example with the workaround:

```
<section>
    <div class="box fifty">1</div>
    <div class="box twentyfive">2</div>
    <div class="box twentyfive">3</div>
    <div class="box fifty">4</div>
    <div class="box fifty">5</div>
</section>


section {
    display: -moz-webkit-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    -ms-flex: auto;
    -moz-flex: auto;
    -webkit-flex: auto;
    flex: auto;
}
.fifty {
    min-width: 50%;
}
.twentyfive {
    min-width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Since this answer will be the most useful for others, I'm marking it as correct. I hope this doesn't go against stackoverflow etiquette though.

Comment: This no longer works in Safari. It doesn’t wrap. It also has inconsistent results. In Firefox it wraps onto a third line.

Comment: BTW the ms prefixes are not needed as IE11 implements without prefix. IE10 uses a different syntax, and you haven't enabled it with a display: -ms-flexbox; anyway. The -moz- prefixes are also not needed as Firefox implemented the final syntax without prefixes.

Comment: you're right. Thanks David! Will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: this post and answer Saved my day! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 7):

Philip Walton has an excellent summary of this bug here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box. He proposes two solutions, the easiest of which is to set `flex-basis: auto` and declare a `width` instead. (Not `max-width` or `min-width`.) This solution has the advantage of not having to adjust your `calc()` when you change padding or border widths.

Answer (score 6):

[This is clearly an IE bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29472649/1588642) so leave the original [correct] CSS and append a hack that targets IE10+:

```
/* IE10+ flex fix: */
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .box {
        flex: 0;
        min-width: 50%;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stedman/t1y8xp2p/