# css calc bug in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox, css-calc

IE11 does not seem to calculate `calc(50% - 1rem)`, but all other browsers do.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10):

According to **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21950351/2756409)**, there is apparently a bug with flexbox and how IE11 handles it. Namely, you cannot use `calc()` with the `flex` shorthand in IE11 as you are trying to do.

I don't have IE11 on this machine, so I can't test any solution for you, nor am I really experienced with flexboxes, but try writing out the property you want to use (e.g. grow, shrink, basis) in long form.

EDIT: After some further research, a *potential* reason for this is that IE11 is trying to [do something stupid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658482/css-calc-function-bug-in-ie) like combine values to allow for decimals. Have you tried something like `calc((50%) - (1rem))`?

Comment: this answer is correct. Do not use the shorthand flex declaration with calc(). flex-basis should be explicitly used. https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#8-flex-basis-doesnt-support-calc