# Bootstrap 3.3.7 "row" causing horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Ok ok, I know.  This question has been asked a lot.  But, so far, I have not found a working solution.  I boiled my page down to nothing but this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

And there is still a horizontal scroll bar.  In dev tools, I can find the `row`:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

And if I un-click `margin-right: -15px;` then the problem goes away.  But, on my actual page (with all of the content) this creates another problem.  The page needs to have zero margins, but it now was a 15px margin on the right.

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969051/bootstrap-3-why-is-row-class-is-wider-than-its-container) sad to wrap `row` with `container-fluid`.  Another said to wrap it in `container`.  Both of these did make the scroll bar go away, but they also give the page side margins, which I can't have.

I've found [threads](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8959) discussing this as far back as 2013.  Is this really not fixed yet?

What do I need to do?

Also: Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/oLx4g8e3/1/

Comment: taking another row inside col will fixit https://jsfiddle.net/oLx4g8e3/3/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all you don't need `row` or `col-*12` classes if your section is 100% wide look at [**this**](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/) bootstrap example they have not taken any `row` or `col-*12` neither with **header** nor **jumbotron**. If your section has column Just take row inside `col-*` classes for example

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">stuff</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">stuff</div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLx4g8e3/4/)**

Or in case if you are using `container-fluid`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">stuff</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">stuff</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLx4g8e3/3/)**

Comment: Really smart solution! I never thought about inverting the order, and putting `.row` inside of `.col-*`... it works perfectly to stop page width elements from causing horizontal overflow.

Comment: Seems like more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: Strange! I think they expect `rows` to be inside at least one bootstrap container. Having row as the absolute parent is causing this issue.

Comment: Both solutions very smart, in their own ways. Thanks for that

Comment: That breaks the row => column heirarchy and practaically ignores bootstrap and might look like a bug to a future developer. A better solution is adding a semantic class that cancels the margin explicitly (like container-fluid does, e.g. row-no-container, or row-nomargins).

Answer (score 22):

If someone is facing this in Bootstrap v4.
Just add `m-0` to your div.

```
<div class="row m-0"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

An easier way is to simply remove the margins on the offending row(s):

```
.row {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about a scrollbar appearing on the bottom of the page when the container is supposed to be fluid? There might be an element in your page that is extending the width of the screen.

I usually use [**this Chrome extension**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb) to see what CSS elements are extending farther than they should.

Also, see if this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oLx4g8e3/2/) helps (code below).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I am talking about a scroll bar appearing on the bottom of the page. (Title updated for clarity).  See the fiddle, where there is nothing but the HTML in my OP.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, your fiddle has margins on the side, which (as I said in the OP) I can't have.

Comment: Let me clear something up- Why can't the page have margins?

Comment: A fair question.  Answer:  because the customer said "No margins" :-)  There is graphical content that needs to bleed all the way to the edge of the screen.

Comment: There's a lot going on there, which is why I created the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oLx4g8e3/1/ which demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: (In other words, it's not worth looking at the actual page where I'm having the trouble. I just want to get a no-margin page with no horizontal scroll working in Fiddle, and then I can go from there.)

Comment: Ah, I see! Flexbox might actually suit your needs here. Let me link [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001013/how-to-remove-left-and-right-margins-from-all-wrapped-rows-in-flexbox-without-n) regarding flexbox having no margins. Pretty sure this will mix with Bootstrap just fine.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Dinner time.  I will digest your link later tonight.

Answer (score 2):

I will just straight away jump to Bootstrap 5 since this is the latest version and everyone is using it currently.

#### Last Updated on Dec 2022

Tested on Bootstrap 5.2 ✔
Tested on Bootstrap 5.1 ✔
Tested on Bootstrap 5.0 ✔

#### Bootstrap 5

If some of you using **Bootstrap 5** you can use `overflow-hidden` to fix this issue. Thought it might help others.

My situation is I had to use `row` inside `container-fluid` and the `row` is not touching the edge of my browser which is want I wanted. When I add `px-0` i get the **horizontal scroll bar**.

After going through the documentation I came across `overflow-hidden`.

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/#horizontal-gutters

[image]

```html
<div class="container-fluid px-0 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <!-- your text -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a container-fluid and completely remove the margin ?

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or make your own div around it with `width: 100%`

Comment: I tried this in fiddle.  It still has margins on the side.

Comment: I will try some things later in fiddle im on mobile, I had the same Problem and tried it with Lots of things and most of them worked;)

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I had to change .container from "width: 100%" to "width: initial".

```
  .container {
    width: initial;
  }
```

If you need to keep width: 100%, you could perhaps also try box-sizing: border-box;

```
  .container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I notice a overflow on my nav.

With angular binding:

```
<div class="row" [style]="{'width': '100%'}">
    <div class="col-12">
        (Your content here)
    </div>
</div>
```

Or inline:

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%">
    <div class="col-12">
        (Your content here)
    </div>
</div>
```

This solved my problem.